# fuelphp html email issue

Tags: fuelphp

I ran into a problem what i cant solve.

i took a look at the fuelphp documentation, made it that way, but i get an error with passed walue

code

```
$email_data = array();
//echo Config::get('base_url'). "user/activate/". $user['hash'];
$email = Email::forge();
$email->from('my@email.me', Config::get('site_name'));
$email->to(Input::post('email'), Input::post('first_name') . " " . Input::post('last_name'));
$email->subject('Regisztráció');

$email_data['name'] = "Kedves " . Input::post('first_name'). " " .Input::post('last_name') ."<br><br>" ;
$email_data['title'] = "Üdvözöllek a ".Config::get('site_name')." oldalán" ."<br>";
$email_data['link'] = '<a href="'.Config::get('site_url'). "user/activate/". $user['hash'].'">Fiókod mherősítéséhez kérlek kattints ide</a>';

$email->html_body(\View::forge('email/activation', $email_data));
$email->send();

$response->body(json_encode(array(
'status' => 'ok',
)));
```

the email template file

```
<?php 

print_r($email_data);
 ?>
```

and the email sends me out this

```
Notice!

ErrorException [ Notice ]: Undefined variable: email_data

APPPATH/views/email/activation.php @ line 3:

2:3:print_r($email_data);4:?>
```

could please someone give me a hint what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$email->html_body(\View::forge('email/activation', $email_data));
```

Should be

```
$email->html_body(\View::forge('email/activation', array('email_data' => $email_data)));
```

Comment: No problem. The amount  of times I've done that made it easy to spot!

Answer (score 1):

Your controller is correct. This is you template that is not correct.

When passing data to the view (template) you pass it as an array.
So you view should be:

```
...
You Name is : <?php echo $name ?>
You title is : <?php echo $title ?>
...
```

This is the way it should be done. Not transforming the array into an element of an other array in order to perform a print_r...